# OTA installation for IOS And Android

Tags: android, ios, installation, ssl-certificate, release-management

I am currently implementing the OTA process portal for uploading the released binaries for Android and IOS specifically.

My Scenario:

I have 20 apps and they keep coming with new binaries every week.

1. I want to have a portal web page where I upload the file received
   from the developer  (Enterprise or for the device who's Id is in
   provisioning profile that is used for this Ipa that is been
   uploaded)
2. I'll enter the bundle / app ID in case if we cant use
   some script to read the app id from IPA
3. Enter build name and
   version
4. Enter icon for the application that will be shown while
   installing.

Currently what we do is make IPA, plist and index.php and then upload with a new folder in one place and then keep updating this plist and ipa, or update the php file and keep adding new plist and ipa manually to make listed entries.

What we want is to keep all the previous historical releases and the latest to be there with generated link shown on webpage to share with out users.

Can you guide with idea how we can achieve this without manual plist making process.

Comment: If  you want to automate an uploading process, as `pList` is just XML in the end. You can generated XML on the fly whenever a new binary is uploaded.

Comment: Do we have any provision  to fill the bundle ID/ app ID, Build name, version name , from the IPA ???